# how to add checkbox column to gridview using sqldataprovider?

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to add a `checkox` column in the **gridview**, I have generated the grid view using the `sqldata provider`, But while using `$data` in the `checkbox` to load the value the following **error** is thrown

> Trying to get property of non-object

here is my view code:

```
'columns'=>array(
  array(                                                                                                                                           
    'header'=>'Select',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>'CHtml::checkBox("user_id",false,array("value"=>"$data->user_id"))',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'style'=>'text-align:center'
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
array("value"=>"$data->user_id"))',
```

To

```
array("value"=>$data->user_id))',
```

Like

```
'columns'=>array(
  array(                                                                                                                                           
    'header'=>'Select',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>'CHtml::checkBox("user_id",false,array("value"=>$data->user_id))',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'style'=>'text-align:center'
   ),
),
```

For more info, [click](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7140-can-i-add-a-checkbox-on-per-row-in-the-cgridview/)